# network services not working after an upgrade

Tags: networking

after  an upgrade when i restarted my sytem ubuntu   14.04 amd 64 no network icon on desktop 
when i click through system setting on network icon, it say "THE SYSTEM NETWORK SERVICES ARE NOT COMPATIBLE WITH THIS VERSION"

Comment: Maybe I have the same problem, same error message, network not working by ethernet nor wifi. Searched the net for anything similar, for people trying to help: How can one "sudo apt-get install" without network? Even simple "install --reinstall" do not work (trying to connect somewhere and fails overall). Things like "sudo service network[/NetworkManager] restart" returns unrecognized service. Any deeper idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your upgrade missed some packages. To make sure everything required is indeed installed, type this in a shell:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

It will bring any package marked as a dependency, which should get you at a better starting point.